# Expire all active sessions at the same time, daily

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

For a Java JSP web application I'm making, I keep an object in a session.
If there are multiple users signed onto the site, each in their own session, I would like for all the session (regardless of when they started) to expire at midnight the same day.

For instance:

> session object 1: creation date (2012-12-11 8:45), expiration date (2012-12-12 0:00)
>
> session object 2: creation date (2012-12-11 12:00), expiration date (2012-12-12 0:00)

And so on, every day the day's sessions getting invalidated.

Some ideas I had was

- to set the session's time until expiration to (the next midnight - the current date), though I'm not entirely confident in my ability to progrematically do this
- schedule some kind of server task to clear all the sessions at midnight every day

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way I see is Option 2

1. Implement a HttpSessionListener - http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html - this will help you collect the active sessions in a Collection using call back methods sessionCreated() and sessionDestroyed().
2. Use a TimerTask - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html that runs every midnight and closes all the active sessions you have collected.

Option 1 is also possible but might be little unpredictable as you have to set a precise timeout every time you create a new session.

Have fun !

Comment: "Might be a little unpredictable as you have to set a precise timeout every time you create a new session." Could you ellaborate on why this would cause unpredictable behaviour?

Comment: Every time request with the session is encountered. You got to find the difference between the "Request time" and "End of the day time". Presuming you will use <http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29> the difference difference you get is in MilliSeconds(long). Then use <http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval%28int%29> in Seconds(int). Hence I feel there MIGHT be some unpredictable results. I am not able to clearly quantify the loss in predictability. Please do post the results if you experiment.

Comment: Using `TimerTask` in a Java EE web application which is supposed to run lifetime long is recipe for major trouble on long run! Rather use container managed scheduler or `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Answer (score 0):

Set the expiration date of the sessions at the end of the current day:

```java
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
today.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
Date expiration = today.getTime();
```